# Is "source" akin to "cause"?

Tags: meaning

I read a sentence which was:

Ocean currents are driven by a range of sources.
The word source generally means something from which any other thing originates. 
So, is source the right word in this sentence?

Comment: I wouldn't use either. If you compare Google hits for your two possibilities with those for [*"driven by a range of **factors**"*](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=IDhTXLvgEKnmgwfjroL4Cw&q=%22driven+by+a+range+of+factors%22&btnK=Google+Search&oq=%22driven+by+a+range+of+factors%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i302i39.6876.6876..8055...2.0..0.149.236.1j1......0....2j1..gws-wiz.....6..35i39.WOFhp0PK29M) you'll see that's the hands-down winner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### "Source" and "cause" can be nearly synonymous

The word *source* can mean *origin* as in "source of water."

*Cause* can also mean *origin* as in "cause of the noise."

Source* refers to the place/institution/entity from which the thing(s) in question originate.

*Cause* refers to the activity/institution/entity that generates the thing(s) in question.

So there's some overlap between the two but they are not always synonymous.

> The *source* of the current is the Pacific ocean. (place)
>
> The current's *cause*/*source* is the Columbia River. (entity)
>
> The *cause* of the Pacific Garbage Patch is the water swirling between the continents. (activity)

---

And as FumbleFingers points out in their comment, there are still other ways to convey the same idea which may yet be more appropriate than either *source* or *cause*.